# How can I possible shorten this JS code to be more readable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    ctrl = {
        dataHolder: {
            hide: _ => {
                this.dataHolderTarget.style.display = 'none'
            },
            show: _ => {
                this.dataHolderTarget.style.display = 'block'
            }
        },
        dataBtnHolder: {
            hide: _ => {
                this.dataBtnHolderTarget.style.display = 'none'
            },
            show: _ => {
                this.dataBtnHolderTarget.style.display = 'block'
            }
        },
        playerOneBtn: {
            hide: _ => {
                this.playerOneBtnTarget.style.display = 'none'
            },
            show: _ => {
                this.playerOneBtnTarget.style.display = 'block'
            },
            load: res=>{
                this.dataset.res=res
            }
        },
        playerTwoBtn: {
            hide: _ => {
                this.playerTwoBtnTarget.style.display = 'none'
            },
            show: _ => {
                this.playerTwoBtnTarget.style.display = 'block'
            },
            load: res=>{
                this.dataset.res=res
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make so I don't repeat those code blocks? As I'm aware of DRY, this code looks somehow ugly. As you can see `hide` and `show` are everywhere. The last 2 elements have `load` functions.

Comment: How are `this.playerTwoBtnTarget` and other elements assigned? How is `ctrl` called? Also, this is probably better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: @adiga the question needs much more context before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed eddien at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight I usually link to their help page before redirecting to another SE site. But, forgot to add that here. I'll use that meta link from next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can refactor the repeated hide/show code to a separate function.

Then, you can refactor creating a `{hide: ..., show: ...}` object for a given element into a separate function:

```
function toggleVisibility(element, displayValue) {
  element.style.display = displayValue;
}

function makeHideShow(target) {
  return {
    hide: () => toggleVisibility(target, "none"),
    show: () => toggleVisibility(target, "block"),
  };
}

ctrl = {
  dataHolder: makeHideShow(this.dataHolderTarget),
  dataBtnHolder: makeHideShow(this.dataBtnHolderTarget),
  playerOneBtn: {
    ...makeHideShow(this.playerOneBtnTarget),
    load: (res) => this.dataset.res = res,
  },
  playerTwoBtn: {
    ...makeHideShow(this.playerTwoBtnTarget),
    load: (res) => this.dataset.res = res,
  },
};
```

Comment: Note that this approach will use the value of `this.dataHolderTarget` at the time that the `ctrl` object is created, and not the value of `this.dataHolderTarget` at the time that the function is invoked. This means you would have to ensure you set `this.dataHolderTarget` prior to constructing the `ctrl` object, and you would not be able to change the value of `this.dataHolderTarget` at a later time. This code is therefore not equivalent to the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demonstration of the extreme lengths you can go to to not repeat yourself...

Note: in this code, although the console.log() output will contain `e` and `b` in the functions, those should be correctly bound to the appropriate values:

```js
const ctrl = Object.fromEntries(
  ['dataHolder','dataBtnHolder','playerOneBtn','playerTwoBtn'].map(i=>[i, {
    ...Object.fromEntries([['hide','none'],['show','block']].map(([a,b])=>
      [a,(e=>(_=>this[e].style.display = b))(`${i}Target`)])),
    ...i.startsWith('player')?{load: res=>this.dataset.res=res}:{}
  }
]))

console.log(ctrl)
```

Comment: keyword "more readable"

Answer (score -1):

```
const elements = ['dataHolderTarget', 'dataBtnHolderTarget', 'playerOneBtnTarget', 'playerTwoBtnTarget'];

const ctrl = {};

elements.forEach(element => {
  ctrl[element] = {
    hide: _ => this[element].style.display = "none",
    show: _ => this[element].style.display = "block"
  };
});

// Add the `load` property to the `playerOneBtn` and `playerTwoBtn` objects.
ctrl.playerOneBtnTarget.load = res => (this.dataset.res = res);
ctrl.playerTwoBtnTarget.load = res => (this.dataset.res = res);
```

In this way, you can avoid repeating yourself when defining the object properties, and you can easily add new elements to the object by simply adding them to the elements array. Additionally, you can easily add new properties to all of the elements by adding them to the object that is created in the forEach loop.